# Schedule a regsvr32 execution on reboot

Tags: shell, com, nsis, reboot, regsvr32

I'm writing an installer on NSIS that registers a shell extension.

On uninstall and upgrade, the old extension can't be deleted/overwritten since explorer.exe locks it, and killing-restarting the process is ruled out.

So I extract the new extension with a different name, mark the old extension for deletion (uninstall/upgrade) and rename the new extension to its original name (upgrade only) via **PendingFileRenameOperations** registry key. So far, this works fine.

The problem is, I have to register the new shell component on startup, since **PendingFileRenameOperations** only works on reboot. Is there a way to schedule a regsvr32 operation after rebooting?

I can't depend on doing this via a .bat execution on **RunOnce**, since logging off/logging on also triggers **RunOnce** operations.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I have found to resolve this issue, is to create a registry script that deletes all related registry keys and values. Run the registry script in the (un-)installer, and schedule a "delete on boot" for the COM DLLs. There might be a better way to do this, but I have yet to find it.

Comment: "Related registry keys" as in all the keys registered for the shell extension to work? Can you modify a COM dll after doing this? 

Nevertheless, it's an idea. I'll try that.